# Printing content of ARRAY inside hash

Tags: perl

how do I print a content of an array inside the hash? I am using Dumper so you can see the data that I am parsing.

```
print Dumper \%loginusers;

 for my $key ( keys %loginusers ) {
        my $value = $loginusers{$key};
        print "$key => $value\n";
 } 


 printf "%s %-32s %-18s\n","User","Hostname","Since";
```

The output is

```
$VAR1 = {
          'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => [
',                                                                                 'user=user1
'                                                                                  'since=2017-03-10 13:53:27
                                                                                 ]
        };

server1.localdomain.com:8080 => ARRAY(0x1584748)
User Hostname                         Since
```

As you can see there is an ARRAY(0x1584748) and I don't know how to get that value inside from the hash.

What I would like to see is something like:

```
User  Hostname                         Since
user1 server1.localdomain.com:8080     2017-03-10 13:53:27
```

Thank you very much for someone that can help.

Update:
So after trying this to see the data how it looks:

```
foreach my $key (keys %loginusers) 
{
    print "For $key:\n";
    print "\t|$_|\n" for @{$loginusers{$key}};
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
For server1.localdomain.com:8080:
|       |user=user1
|       |since=2017-03-10 13:53:27
```

Update:
tried the add these on the code:

```
foreach my $key (keys %loginusers)
{
    my @fields =
        map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*\Z//; s/\s*\n\s*/ /g; $_ }
        grep { /\S/ }
            @{$loginusers{$key}};

    print "For $key:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @fields;
}
```

And using the both sample code:

```
printf "%-8s %-32s %s\n", qw(User Hostname Since);
foreach my $key (keys %loginusers)
{
    my %field = map { /\s*(.*?)=\s*(.*)/ } @{$loginusers{$key}};
    my ($host, $rgsender, $port) = split /:/, $key;
    printf "%-8s %-32s %s\n", $field{user}, $host, $field{since};
}


my $newusers;
for my $host ( keys %loginusers ) {
    local $/ = "\r\n"; #localised "input record separator" for the "chomp"
    %{$newusers->{$host}} = map { chomp; split /=/,$_,2 } @{$loginusers{$host}};
}
undef %loginusers;  #not needed anymore
#print "NEW STRUCTURE: ", Dumper $newusers;

printline( qw(User Hostname Since) );
printline($newusers->{$_}{user}, $_, $newusers->{$_}{since}) for (keys %$newusers);

sub printline { printf "%-8s %-32s %-18s\n", @_; }
```

and here is the results:

```
User     Hostname                          Since
user1    server1.localdomain.com:8080      2017-03-10 13:53:27
User     Hostname                          Since
user1    server1.localdomain.com:8080      2017-03-10 13:53:27
```

Comment: `print "$key => @$value\n";` => http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS

Comment: You can do `my @data = @{$value}` to get a regular array.

Comment: Where does `user1` come from? It shows up out of nowhere.

Comment: @zdim it is just a sample of the data that I would like to parse.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, way past the right margin. Sorry.  Btw, why all that space? Is that in your data?

Comment: @zdim yeah that is the raw data and exact the same data that i want to parse

Comment: But it doesn't make sense.  I had to put it in a file here in order to see what it is ... and there are linebreaks in the middle.  When I join it I get `'server1.localdomain.com:8080'` and `[','user=user1 ''since=2017-03-10 13:53:27 ]`. That's not a valid arrayref.  Can you show some actual data? It looks like it is confusing `Dumper` so it is not clear _what_ needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hash value is a scalar, and it can take a reference.  This is how we build complex data structures. Yours apparently have arrayrefs, so you need to dereference them. Something like

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    say "$key => @{$hash{key}}";
}
```

See the tutorial [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and the cookbook on data structures [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

The strange output from `Dumper` indicates that there may be leading/trailing spaces around values (or worse), which need be cleaned out. Until this is clarified I'll assume data like

```
'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => ['user=user1', 'since=2017-03-10 13:53:27']
```

In order to get the desired output you need to split each element

```
printf "%-8s %-32s %s\n", qw(User Hostname Since);
foreach my $key (keys %hash)
{
    my ($user, $since) = map { /=\s*(.*)/ } @{$hash{$key}};

    printf "%-8s %-32s %s\n", $user, $key, $since;
}
```

For each value, we dereference it and pass that through [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). The code in `map`s block, that is applied to each element, pulls what is after `=`. Given the data, the first one is the user and the second one is timestamp.  Since this is an array (and not a hash) I assume that the order is fixed. If not, get strings from both sides of `=` and analyze them to see which one goes where. Or better use a hash

```
my %field = map { /\s*(.*?)=\s*(.*)/ } @{$hash{$key}};
```

where `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`, capturing until the *first* `=`. Then print as

```
printf "%-8s %-32s %s\n", $field{user}, $key, $field{since};
```

and you don't rely on the order in the arrayref. See the [answer by jm666](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852517/4653379) for a nice and consistent approach building this from the beginning.

With the hash shown above this prints

```
User     Hostname                         Since
user1    server1.localdomain.com:8080     2017-03-10 13:53:27
```

I've used `8` and `32` widths based on shown data.  For more precision, there are modules for tabular output. If you do it by hand you need to pre-process and find the longest word *for each column* among keys and/or values, and then use those lengths in the second pass with `printf`.

---

It appears that `Dumper` is getting confused by strange data. To see what we have do

```
foreach my $key (keys %loginusers) 
{
    print "For $key:\n";
    print "\t|$_|\n" for @{$loginusers{$key}};
}
```

To clean up the data you can try

```
foreach my $key (keys %loginusers) 
{
    my @fields = 
        map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; s/\s*\R\s*/ /g; $_ } 
        grep { /\S/ } 
            @{$loginusers{$key}};

    print "For $key:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @fields;
}
```

The `grep` takes an input list and filters out those elements for which the code inside its block evaluates false. Here we require at least one non-space character. Then its output goes into `map`, which removes all leading and trailing whitespace, and replaces all newlines with spaces.

Comment: I tried now:

foreach my $key (keys %loginusers) {
    print "$key => @{$loginusers{$key}}";
}

and the result is:
 since=2017-03-10 13:53:27net:server1.localdomain.com:8080 => user=user1

Comment: @webdev.gk  Cleaned out a couple of typos.  The test prints the desired output (I think?)

Comment: @webdev.gk  Cleaned out a bug -- can't use non-space `\S` in regex, since there _are_ spaces inside the string after `=`)

Comment: you are genius and its almost complete. 

So if I use this, the output is almost complete except that the since doesn't not have the hours,mins and seconds. it only shows 2017-03-10
 my ($user, $since) = map { /=\s*(\S+)/ } @{$loginusers{$key}}; 

If i use this code below, it is complete except that user is not showing
my ($user, $since) = map { /=\s*(.*)/ } @{$loginusers{$key}}

Comment: @webdev.gk  That is what my previous comment says -- it was a bug, and I fixed it in the post.  Look at it again.  The error was that I was using "non-space" (`\S`) in the regex so the last part got left out.  Now the regex uses `.*`, so _everything_ up to the end of the string.

Comment: strange because I copied all the code just now and when I tried, it is missing the user but the since is complete with date and hours

Comment: @webdev.gk The output I show is copied from my terminal. But note, I use the cleaned out data, shown in the answer.  I think that something may be badly wrong with your data -- can you just print them to screen (not with `Dumper`) and see what it is like?  Use the code at the beginning of my answer, or even first nicely make a separate array and print an element per line.

Comment: @webdev.gk   I added a more solid way, to split elemts into a hash. See @jm666 answer, that  is a nice way to do it, first clean up the data.  But, something seems badly off with your data.  Remember that `Dumper` prints stuff out of a complex data structure, and it can get confused.  The loose `,` and `'` can't be there -- that is _not a valid arrayref_, so it is clear that `Dumper` has a problem.  Can you do what I suggest in the above comment, and print data out separately to see what you are dealing with?

Comment: @webdev.gk I added to the post a way to see what you have, without `Dumper`.  Please try this and let us know.  Best would be to update the question -- add to the bottom how the data looks.

Comment: @webdev.gk Yes, great -- thank you.  I added to the end of my answer, how to try to clean it out.  There is still one bit I don't understand in what you added, but try this.

Comment: @webdev.gk  You are welcome :)  Glad that it all worked out -- and hopefully there was a chance to learn more :)

Comment: yeah I need to learn more on Perl and i'll try my best thank you :)

Comment: honestly I don't know. How do I do that? I already click jm666 answer as useful and yes it is

Comment: yeah I agree.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The your data-structure isn't very nice. I would convert it to some better, using:

```
#convert to better structure
my $newusers;
for my $host ( keys %loginusers ) {
        %{$newusers->{$host}} = map { chomp; split /=/,$_,2 } @{$loginusers{$host}};
}
undef %loginusers;      #the old not needed anymore
print "NEW STRUCTURE: ", Dumper $newusers;
```

The dump now looks like:

```
NEW STRUCTURE: $VAR1 = {
          'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => {
                                              'user' => 'user1',
                                              'since' => '2017-03-10 13:53:27'
                                            }
        };
```

after the above the printing is simple:

```
printline( qw(User Hostname Since) );
printline($newusers->{$_}{user}, $_, $newusers->{$_}{since}) for (keys %$newusers);

sub printline { printf "%-8s %-32s %-18s\n", @_; }
```

For the explanation read @zdim's excellent answer (and accept his answer :))

full code

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %loginusers = (
'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => [
        "user=user1\r\n",   # you probably have the \r too
        "since=2017-03-10 13:53:27\r\n",
     ]
);
say "OLD STRUCTURE: ", Dumper \%loginusers;

#convert to better structure
my $newusers;
for my $host ( keys %loginusers ) {
    %{$newusers->{$host}} = map { s/[\r\n]//g; split /=/, $_, 2 } @{$loginusers{$host}}; #removes all \r and \n
} 
undef %loginusers;  #not needed anymore
say "NEW STRUCTURE: ", Dumper $newusers;

printline( qw(User Hostname Since) );
printline($newusers->{$_}{user}, $_, $newusers->{$_}{since}) for (keys %$newusers);

sub printline { printf "%-8s %-32s %-18s\n", @_; }
```

result:

```
OLD STRUCTURE: $VAR1 = {
          'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => [
                                              'user=user1
',
                                              'since=2017-03-10 13:53:27
'
                                            ]
        };

NEW STRUCTURE: $VAR1 = {
          'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => {
                                              'user' => 'user1',
                                              'since' => '2017-03-10 13:53:27'
                                            }
        };

User     Hostname                         Since             
user1    server1.localdomain.com:8080     2017-03-10 13:53:27
```

## EDIT

You probably have the `\r` in your data too. See the updated code.

Comment: thank you. my data structure is a bit different from the output you showed. mine is like this and not nice..

NEW STRUCTURE: $VAR1 = {
          'server1.localdomain.com:8080' => {
',                                                                                 'since' => '2017-03-10 13:53:27
'                                                                                  'user' => 'user1
                                                                                 }
        };

if you look, there is unwanted " ' " and after the user it is missing another " ' "

Comment: @webdev.gk added a full demo

Comment: @webdev.gk see the edit and the full demo again - your data probably contains not only the `\n` but the `\r` too. *it would be best clean your data beforehand*.

Comment: yes your suggestion to clean the data fix those problems